# How to pass object id to django view when handling multiple different models objects in the same view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I am trying to make web app which has dashboard on main page where user can add saved links, notes reminders and etc. I figured out how to use several forms in same view to create different model objects, but I'm not able to update those objects. What I am specificaly trying to do is to have one button form and when user click on that button (checkbox) reminder object status changes to closed. But I can't find a way to get that object ID or anything to query it in my view.

I am very new to Django framework it might be something obvious, but I coudn't find any information that would help me and I tried a lot of variations to achieve this, but nothing worked so far.

**models.py**

```
class Reminders(models.Model):
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="reminder_about", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="reminder_for", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reminder'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reminders'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.status} {self.note}"
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    current_user = request.user
    person = Person.objects.get(user=current_user)
    scheduled_calls = ScheduledCalls.objects.filter(user_id=person.id).order_by("-date")
    reminders = Reminders.objects.filter(user_id=person.id).order_by("-date")
    notes = Notes.objects.filter(user_id=person.id).order_by("-date")
    links = SavedLinks.objects.filter(user_id = person.id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        call_form = _get_form(request, CallForm, "call_form_pre")
        link_form = _get_form(request, LinkForm, "link_form_pre")
        note_form = _get_form(request, NotesForm, "note_form_pre")
        reminder_form = _get_form(request, RemindersForm, "reminder_form_pre")
        remindercheck_form = _get_form(request, RemindersForm, "remindercheck_form_pre")

        if call_form.is_bound and call_form.is_valid():
            call_form.instance.user_id = person
            call_form.save(commit=False)
            call_form.save()
            return redirect("home")

        if link_form.is_bound and link_form.is_valid():
            link_form.instance.user_id = person
            link_form.save(commit=False)
            link_form.save()
            return redirect("home")
        
        if note_form.is_bound and note_form.is_valid():
            note_form.instance.user_id = person
            note_form.save(commit=False)
            note_form.save()
            return redirect("home")
        
        if reminder_form.is_bound and reminder_form.is_valid():
            reminder_form.instance.user_id = person
            reminder_form.save(commit=False)
            reminder_form.save()
            return redirect("home")
        
        #this is the part im stuck with     
        if remindercheck_form.is_bound:
            note = request.POST("note")
            reminder = Reminders.objects.filter(note=note)
            reminder.update(status="Closed")
        
    return render(request, "main/home.html", {"person" : person, 
                                              "scheduled_calls" : scheduled_calls, 
                                              "reminders" : reminders, 
                                              "notes" : notes,
                                              "links" : links, 
                                              "call_form" : CallForm(prefix = "call_form_pre"),
                                              "link_form" : LinkForm(prefix = "link_form_pre"),
                                              "note_form" : NotesForm(prefix = "note_form_pre"),
                                              "reminder_form" : RemindersForm(prefix = "reminder_form_pre"),
                                              "remindercheck_form" : RemindersForm(prefix = "remindercheck_form_pre"),
                                              })
```

**html**

```
<div id="tabs" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:14rem;"> 
            {% if reminders %}
                {% for reminder in reminders %}
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-0 my-1">
                  <form action="" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input id="remdone" name="{{remindercheck_form.prefix}}" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="False">
                      <input class="form-check-label" style="border: 0px; background-color: white; color: black;" name="note"
                                value="{{reminder.note}}" disabled>
                      <input name="status" type="text" class="form-control" value="Closed" hidden>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(document).ready(function() { 
                      $('input[id=remdone]').change(function(){
                           $('form').submit();
                      });
                     });
                   </script>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
              <h5 class="text-center mt-5">You did a good job! No reminders left!</h5>    
              {% endif %}
          </div>
```

**forms.py**

```
class RemindersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reminders
        fields = ("note", "person_id", "status")

        widgets = {
            "person_id" : forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "note" : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "status" : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RemindersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['person_id'].empty_label = " "
        self.fields['person_id'].queryset = Person.objects.all()
```

**Edit**

To be clearer added how it looks in front-end. When user clicks checkbox item status in database should change to closed and item should dissappear from list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a simplier way to achieve what i needed. Since I didn't need any input from user i ditched forms entirely and for "Checkbox" used href with link which has status handling view. View doesn't have render only redirect so upon click I stay on the same page as I wanted, but item status actually changes for item clicked since I pass it's ID to view from URL.

```
#views.py
def reminder_update(request, reminder_id):
    item = Reminders.objects.get(pk=reminder_id)
    item.status = True
    item.save()
    return redirect("home")
    
#urls.py
path("reminder/<reminder_id>", views.reminder_update, 
name="reminder_update")
    
#html
{% if reminders %}
    {% for reminder in reminders %}
        <div>
            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{% url 
'reminder_update' reminder.id %}">
            <img src="{% static 'images/elements/Checkbox.png' %}"
             alt=""
             width="17"
             style="cursor: pointer; padding-bottom: 0.1rem; margin-right: 
0.5rem;"/>
             </a>
             {{reminder.note}}    
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by pass the reminder id to the form by including it as a hidden input field in the form. Then, in your view, you can retrieve the reminder object based on the id and update its status.

I do have the same issue before which I fix using this technique. This way, when the user clicks the checkbox, the form is submitted with the reminder id, and your view can update the reminder object accordingly.
firstly you need to update your view function with

```
if remindercheck_form.is_bound:
    reminder_id = request.POST.get("reminder_id") 
    reminder = get_object_or_404(Reminders, id=reminder_id)
    reminder.status = "Closed" 
    reminder.save()
```

You also need to import the get_object_or_400 as

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```

and in the html template add the input field as follows

```
<input type="hidden" name="reminder_id" value="{{ reminder.id }}">
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exacly what I tried to achieve, but one thing what is still not working is that when I try to "close" my reminder I can do it only from the last item in list and in that order. If I try to "close" first item or middle item in list it won't do nothing. Maybe you have any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

At first you should pay attention to the models.py file that you used Person model that i can't see but it seems to be a user customized model.

You don't need to add id for every reminder so you can recode models.py like this:

**models.py**

```
class Reminders(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="reminder_about", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="reminder_for", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reminder'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reminders'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.status} {self.note}"
```

then in your `view.py` file you need to cleaner code and use the user object to fill the foreign key in another model.

also if you want to update every model in your `views.py` file, please make a query of database and use `update()` method like this:

**views.py**

```
if note_form.is_bound and note_form.is_valid():
    new_note_set = models.Note.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(person=person)
    new_note_set.save()
```

for the end point, usually django developers define a variable and name it `context`:

```
context = {
            ...
            "person" : person, 
            "scheduled_calls" : scheduled_calls, 
            ...
        }

return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Comment: Not sure if I got this right, if i will make suggested edits in front-end user will be able to press checkbox on selected item(reminder) and only that one item will be updated? I am asking because you suggested to query by user, but all of the items returned in for loop are with same user. So won't be all of the items updated?

Comment: In the views.py file you have 4 same conditionl statements, so i write 1 example of them and you can use it to other conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

answer to your question for the closing of the reminder

as I think you're already getting the reminder_id now use this reminder_id to delete/close the proper reminder. The modified code will be like this

```
if remindercheck_form.is_bound:
        note = request.POST("note")
        reminder = Reminders.objects.filter(note=note, id=reminder_id)
        reminder.update(status="Closed")
```

I think this will work as you needed

Comment: I tried to check why it is closing wrong reminder and noticed that reminder_id value in html is returned correctly, but when i added print to console reminder_id value passed to view upon pressing submit button is different from what am I getting in html. Not sure why it is happening. Can it be because html form itself is generated in for loop and all items form has same name?